# One result in MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this tables

**ORDERS**

- orders_id
- order_article_id
- order_invoice_id
- order_customer_id
- order_qty

**ARTICLES**

- articles_id
- article_name
- article_qty
- article_price
- article_amount

**CUSTOMERS**

- customers_id
- customer_name
- customer_position
- customer_office

**INVOICES**

- invoices_id
- date
- invoice_customer_id

And SQL Join Table

```
$sql="SELECT customer_name, invoices_id, SUM( order_qty * article_price ) AS amount, article_name
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN articles ON order_article_id = articles_id
LEFT JOIN invoices ON order_invoice_id = invoices_id
LEFT JOIN customers ON order_customer_id = customers_id
WHERE invoices_id =1
GROUP BY customer_name, invoices_id
LIMIT 0 , 30"
```

This way i got result

- customer_name
- invoices_id
- amount
- article_name

The problem is here in article_name? I have several article name,, but i got only first result?

Comment: This is due to `article_name` being left out of the `GROUP BY`. MySQL allows this (often with unexpected results) while most other RDBMS would report an error and disallow it.  Please post a small sample of the rows from each table together with a sample of what the query output should be. However, it might be as simple as adding `article_name` to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I guess that you have only one article bound to an order. If the list of article is the most important, you should start with articles table, then join others tables.